# airodump-ng doesn't detect my pc but detects all other machines

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I am having trouble these past few days wile trying to detect my testing PC with airodump-ng.

Here is my configuration :

PC1 :
Windows 10 with VirtualBox running Kali Linux
Alfa AWUS036H network adapter.

PC2 : 
Windows 10
Wireless adapter : Intel Centurino Advanced-N 6235

On Kali (on PC1), I turned my alfa to monitor mode.
When I run airodum-ng, I can see all the other machines connected to my network :
command used : airodump-ng --bssid  --channel 11 wlan0mon
output :

```
BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe                                                                                  
<bssid> <station_addr>  -58    5e-11e   611      100             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -35    0 -48    483       26             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -39    0 - 1      0       15             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -43    0 -24e     2       12             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -51    0 -24e     7        4             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -58    0 - 1e     0        1             
<bssid  <station_addr>  -60    0 - 1e     2        3
```

In all of the stations discovered I can't find the mac address of the wifi adapter of PC2.
I have tried disabling the firewall and even the antivirus with no success.

I tried a simple deauth on all discovered machines and it works, but on PC2 all the packets are lost (sometimes 1 or 2 get the acknowledge, but it's not enough ...).

I can ping PC2 from PC1.

I hope someone can give me a hint.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to transmit ARP packets to the network via one adapter on
the host, and you expect that it will loop around and come back to the same host
through the other adapter, and that same host will then send an answer that,
again, will loop around back to its first adapter.

You are forgetting here that in actual fact you do not have two operating
systems on the host computer. You only have Windows running on the host,
which executes a program called VirtualBox that runs on top of Windows
and uses its services for TCP and more.

So in effect you are expecting Windows to be sending and receiving at the
same time on two adapters that are connected to the same network,
when the Windows network driver knows well that any TCP network is limited
to only one active sender at any one time, meaning only one adapter.

You would maybe have a better chance for this working if you used
Windows Server with a good network driver,
but with other Windows versions you are even more in the hands of the
driver and its limitations by design of implementation.

I quote from National Instruments
[Best Practices for Using Multiple Network Interfaces (NICs) with NI Products](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12558/en/):

> **Rule 2: Avoid Assigning Multiple NICs in the Same Computer to the Same Subnet**
>
> Using multiple NICs on the same subnet is the #1 cause of connectivity issues on multi-NIC systems. While some OSs may be able to gracefully handle the presence of multiple NICs on one subnet, others may mistakenly attempt to send packets out of the wrong interface. You can remedy this issue by statically assigning one NIC (and the other networked computers attached to that NIC) to the 192.168.x.x range with subnet mask 255.255.0.0, and another NIC on the 10.0.x.x range with subnet mask 255.255.0.0. Note that this is just one possible configuration, any combination of two or more different subnets will work.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer, I have been very busy these days.
My alfa NIC is in monitor mode after I launch airmon-ng wlan0 start. I am not connected to Wifi anymore, so I guess I am not in any subnet.